# Matplotlib - creating a graph with a CheckButton legend for an indefinite amount of plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, subplot, tkinter.checkbutton

I know how to create a legend for a graph which is a series of CheckButtons using the method found here:
https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/widgets/check_buttons.html

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import CheckButtons

t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s0 = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
s1 = np.sin(4*np.pi*t)
s2 = np.sin(6*np.pi*t)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
l0, = ax.plot(t, s0, visible=False, lw=2, color='k', label='2 Hz')
l1, = ax.plot(t, s1, lw=2, color='r', label='4 Hz')
l2, = ax.plot(t, s2, lw=2, color='g', label='6 Hz')
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.2)

lines = [l0, l1, l2]

# Make checkbuttons with all plotted lines with correct visibility
rax = plt.axes([0.05, 0.4, 0.1, 0.15])
labels = [str(line.get_label()) for line in lines]
visibility = [line.get_visible() for line in lines]
check = CheckButtons(rax, labels, visibility)


def func(label):
    index = labels.index(label)
    lines[index].set_visible(not lines[index].get_visible())
    plt.draw()

check.on_clicked(func)

plt.show()
```

My particular problem has an amount of graphs which will be ever growing as we test more samples. How can I structure my code so that the list, which in the attached code is called **lines** can constantly be having new plt.subplots entries added to it when the code is ran or updated?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can do something like this and create a function that returns the line handles.  Then use append to update the list.  As your subplots grow call the `addplotlines` custom function to create addtional handles.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import CheckButtons

t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s0 = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
s1 = np.sin(4*np.pi*t)
s2 = np.sin(6*np.pi*t)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

def addplotlines(t,s, color, label, visible=True):
    l, = ax.plot(t, s, visible=visible, lw=2, color=color, label=label)
    plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.2)
    return l

lines = []
lines.append(addplotlines(t, s0, 'k', '2 Hz', False))
lines.append(addplotlines(t, s1, 'r', '4 Hz', True))
lines.append(addplotlines(t, s2, 'g', '6 Hz', True))

# Make checkbuttons with all plotted lines with correct visibility
rax = plt.axes([0.05, 0.4, 0.1, 0.15])
labels = [str(line.get_label()) for line in lines]
visibility = [line.get_visible() for line in lines]
check = CheckButtons(rax, labels, visibility)


def func(label):
    index = labels.index(label)
    lines[index].set_visible(not lines[index].get_visible())
    plt.draw()

check.on_clicked(func)

plt.show()
```